# Getting error on replace() in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I get 2 errors when I run this script (python3.6). I've tried to solve the issue, but I can't understand the error itself. I'm just a beginner in this.

```
import random
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%)":
        "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self. ***)":
        "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
        "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
        "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
        "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@",
    "***.*** = '***'":
        "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# if they want to drill phrases first
PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "English":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snip, phra):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snip.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snip.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snip.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1, 3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snip, phra:
        result = sentence[:]

        # fake class names
        for var1 in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", var1, 1)

        # fake other names
        for var2 in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", var2, 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for var3 in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", var3, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results


# keep going until they hit CTRL + D
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.choice(list(snippets))

        for snipp in snippets:
            phras = PHRASES[snipp]
            question, answer = convert(snipp, phras)

            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print(question)

            input(">>> ")
            print("ANSWER : %s\n\n" % answer)
except EOFError:
    print("\nBye")
```

The Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/GAUTAM/Droid/PycharmProjects/Python_HardWay/oop_test.py", line 75, in <module>
    question, answer = convert(snipp, phras)
  File "F:/GAUTAM/Droid/PycharmProjects/Python_HardWay/oop_test.py", line 52, in convert
    result = result.replace("%%%", var1, 1)
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not bytes
```

I tried doing numerous things. But, nothing seemed to work. Why do I get an error when I put the questions and answers in the func convert.
I saw this code in a book "Learn Python, The Hard Way."

The script was on Python 2. I tried to write it in Python 3.

Comment: `urlopen().readlines()` returns `bytes` objects, not strings. You need to decode those via the correct encoding. For example `WORDS.append(word.decode("utf-8").strip())` in your loop where you `# load up the words from the website`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. So you should consider using a tutorial that's aimed at Python 3. There are some suggestions in [What tutorial should I read?](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: One of the big differences between Python 2 & 3 is that Python 3 makes a clear distinction between bytes and text strings, and in Python 3 all text strings are Unicode objects. So trying to learn proper Python 3 string handling from a Python 2 tutorial is not a good plan.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm gonna complete LPTHW. Do you think it's wise for me  to start again with "Dive into Python 3"???

Comment: Fair enough. I can understand you wanting to finish something you've started, that's generally a very good attitude. OTOH, learning Python 2 now as a precursor to learning Python 3 is a bit like learning Shakespearean English as a precursor to learning modern English. ;) You'll being learning stuff you won't need and will have to un-learn. But your time spent so far on LPTHW isn't totally wasted. When you _do_ start on a Python 3 tutorial like "Dive into Python 3" there will be a lot of stuff that you can work through very quickly because it's the same in both Python 2 & Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring 
Alright! Thanks for helping out!!! ;-)

Comment: It might seem that learning Python 2 first and then extending your knowledge to Python 3 is a logical progression. But really, the main changes that Python 3 has made are mostly because certain language features of Python 2 turned out to be bad design choices. So it's actually easier to learn Python 3 first, and then when your Python 3 knowledge is solid you can go back and learn the old-fashioned stuff, if you need to maintain or read old code.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok! So, python 3 will be much easier to learn than 2 bcoz the syntax is easier to code, I guess??? However, the logic behind the various functions remain the same right?? For eg: The concept of class and object remains same in both python 3 and 2, right??

Comment: Yes, virtually all the core concepts are identical, but there are some important changes that affect how you do things, the main one being the text vs bytes thing I mentioned earlier. Another important difference is that many of the built-in functions and methods in Python 2 that returned lists now return iterators in Python 3 (like the difference between Python 2's `range` vs `xrange`). This makes them more RAM-friendly, but sometimes you _do_ need an actual list, and in those cases an expression that worked ok in Python 2 may need to get wrapped in a `list()` call.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok! Will definitely check out python 3 tutorials ASAP!!!
;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlopen().readlines()` returns bytes objects, not strings. You need to decode those via the correct encoding. For example `WORDS.append(word.decode("utf-8").strip())` in your loop where you load up the words from the website. – Jeronimo